# synthesizing an audio pitch in python

Tags: python, audio

i was wondering if there is a way to set the audio pitch. A certain tone would be the base. i want to know how to make the pitch go up or down. thanks.

also how do you play an audio tone. also if you know about any modules that do this, i would like to know them thanks.

my goal is to create a pong game that a blind person could play. the higher the ball is, the higher the pitch. the lower the ball, the lower the pitch. preferably in python. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try pyaudio library, then you can use this function piece of code I created some days ago!

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import math

SHRT_MAX=32767 # short uses 16 bits in complement 2

def my_sin(t,frequency):
    radians = t * frequency * 2.0 * math.pi
    pulse = math.sin(radians)
    return pulse

#pulse_function creates numbers in [-1,1] interval
def generate(duration = 5,pulse_function = (lambda t: my_sin(t,1000))):
    sample_width=2  
    sample_rate = 44100
    sample_duration = 1.0/sample_rate
    total_samples = int(sample_rate * duration)
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    pformat = p.get_format_from_width(sample_width)
    stream = p.open(format=pformat,channels=1,rate=sample_rate,output=True)
    for n in range(total_samples):
        t = n*sample_duration
        pulse = int(SHRT_MAX*pulse_function(t))
        data=struct.pack("h",pulse)
        stream.write(data)

#example of a function I took from wikipedia.
major_chord = f = lambda t: (my_sin(t,440)+my_sin(t,550)+my_sin(t,660))/3

#choose any frequency you want
#choose amplitude from 0 to 1
def create_pulse_function(frequency=1000,amplitude=1):
    return lambda t: amplitude * my_sin(t,frequency)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # play fundamental sound at 1000Hz for 5 seconds at maximum intensity
    f = create_pulse_function(1000,1)
    generate(pulse_function=f)
    # play fundamental sound at 500Hz for 5 seconds at maximum intensity
    f = create_pulse_function(500,1)
    generate(pulse_function=f)
    # play fundamental sound at 500Hz for 5 seconds at 50% intensity
    f = create_pulse_function(500,0.5)
    generate(pulse_function=f)
```

Comment: which line changes the pitch/tone? thanks for this code

Comment: you need to learn from google what tones/pitches are common and go from there. You can only change sound intensity and frequency. If I was you, I would play with values. I edited the code with example

Comment: thanks for accepting! I this your first time making a pong game?

Comment: yeah. im doing this first then im going to work on a database AI.

Comment: @ChrisHawley are you going to make the game multiplayer?

Comment: At first it will just bounce back without a opposing player for debuging purposes. after that is where i want it, i will add in a secondary player option. Not sure i said this already but the goal is to make a pong that can be played by the blind. still trying to figure out how they can tell where the paddle is though

Comment: seems a cool project, could I help you? give ideas?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry its taken me so long to get back to you. I will setup a basic GIT server and create a project for it. how do you want me to send you the information?